# user authentication with angular and passport.js

Tags: node.js, angular

I am unable to perform authentication with angular, node(passport.js) and MongoDB. Below are the detailed codes:

**Angular Part:**

**login.component.html:**

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

**login.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from 
    '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {};
    onSubmit(loginForm) {
        console.log(loginForm.value);
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
        let data = JSON.stringify(loginForm.value);
        this.httpClient.post(url, {data},{responseType: 
            'text'}).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
   }
}
```

**Node Part:**

**routes.js:**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', 
    failureRedirect : '/login',
}));
```

**passport.js:**

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) { 
    console.log("entering function");
    var newUser = new User();
    User.findOne({ 'email' :  email}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user || !newUser.validatePassword(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false);
        } 
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));

};
```

The problem is even I give correct credentials it will always redirecting to failure page(login page).

I hope after the api call, it is not hitting the passport.js file for further authentication.

I am not seeing any text printing in console as I have given in passport.js.

Without angular, I have checked and its working fine. But I need it to do with angular as front-end.

Need someone's help to find where I am wrong also how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.